# Несколько ListBox с выбранным только одним элементом и получением значения данного элемента

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

*Сложно сформировать вопрос правильно, если считаете нужным - поправьте.*

Итак, у меня возникла ситуация, что необходимо, что-бы для нескольких ListBox'ов был только один выбранный предмет за раз. Решение [нашлось](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12761504/8361539) через AP.

Все работает хорошо, но вот возник вопрос - как модифицировать представленный там класс так, что-бы можно было получить выделенный объект у группы ListBox'ов, не проверять же значение каждого, входящего в группу.

Попытался внедрить `Dictionary<string,object>`, в котором хранить подобное, перезаписывая каждый раз при вызове `SelectorOnSelectionChanged`. Но тут выскочило несколько проблем - при смене группы элемента нельзя определить, есть ли еще элементы с такими группами, иначе запись будет уже неактуальной; Еще одна проблема заключается в том, что у селектора свойство `SelectedItem` для `ListBox'a` - обьект ListBoxItem, а у него нельзя получить Content в чистом виде.

Как можно реализовать подобное?

Comment: Мне кажется это решается привязкой к одному ViewModel, в котором находятся данные нужных вам ListBox

Допустим GroupListBoxViewModel в котором ListBoxViewModel. И далее public object Selected(или как то так). Т.е поле, которое выбрано в ListBox обычно(а в данном случае поле будет одно). Ну и если не ошибась при выталкивание объекта вы будете оповещать все ListBox, что сделали это. При помещении если такого объекта у себя они не найдут, то снимум выделение(или подобное). Вроде так и делал, но это не точно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, я разобрался как устранить все проблемы, которые я нашел в [этом примере](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12761504/8361539).
Собственно, объявляем словарь для хранения всех ListBox'ов:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, List<ListBox>> groups = new Dictionary<string, List<ListBox>>();
```

После этого изменяем метод `OnGroupNameChanged` для того, что-бы добавлять и убирать `ListBox'ы`, убрав это проблему

> при смене группы элемента нельзя определить, есть ли еще элементы с такими группами, иначе запись будет уже неактуальной

```
private static void OnGroupNameChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    var lb = (ListBox) dependencyObject;
    var selector = (Selector)dependencyObject;
    if (e.OldValue != null) {
        selector.SelectionChanged -= SelectorOnSelectionChanged;
        groups[e.OldValue.ToString()].Remove(lb);
        if (groups[e.OldValue.ToString()].Count == 0)
            groups.Remove(e.OldValue.ToString());
    }

    if (e.NewValue != null) {
        selector.SelectionChanged += SelectorOnSelectionChanged;
        if (!groups.ContainsKey(e.NewValue.ToString())) {
            groups.Add(e.NewValue.ToString(), new List<ListBox>());
        }
        groups[e.NewValue.ToString()].Add(lb);
    }
}
```

И реализуем метод, с помощью которого можно будет получить контент выделенного элемента в нескольких ListBox'ах:

```
public static object GetSelectedContentByGroup(string groupName) { return ((ListBoxItem) groups[groupName].Find(x => x.SelectedIndex != -1).SelectedItem).Content; }
```